# Specific conditions for the attractors of dynamics

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

Lets say we have a set of vectors $\{\bar v_1, \dots, \bar v_N\}$, with $\bar v_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$. What we know about $f$, is that it can be factorized in three different functions, i.e., $f = a \circ b \circ c$, such that:

- The first function $a : \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ uses a similarity function $\kappa: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to compute the similarity of a given input $\bar x$ with every vector $\bar v_i$. Hence, we have $a(\bar x)_i = \kappa(\bar x,\bar v_i)$ for every index $i$.
- The second function is a continuous function $b: \mathbb{R}^N \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$.
- The third function is known: $c(\bar x) = M^T \bar x$, where $M$ is the matrix whose columns are the vectors $\bar v_i$. For example, if $\bar x$ is a one-hot vector with $i$-th entry equal to one, we have $c(\bar x) = \bar v_i$.

**Example**. Let $\kappa$ be a dot product, so that we have $a(\bar x)_i = \langle\bar x,\bar v_i\rangle$, and $b$ be the softmax function. With these conditions, we have that the initial function $f$ has the vectors $\{\bar v_1, \dots, \bar v_N\}$ as attractors of the dynamics.

**Here comes my question**, which aims to generalize the above results:
What are the minimal conditions on the functions $a$ and $b$ ensuring that the initial function $f$ has $\{\bar v_1, \dots, \bar v_N\}$ as attractors? I would assume that $\kappa$ has to be some sort of similarity function (altought I'm not finding any formal definition of it online), and $b$ has to be a function that, given any vector, multiple iterations of it converge to a 1-hot vector. However, I'm struggling into finding the details. What would be a formal argument saying that "If $\kappa$ has properties $XY$ and $b$ has property $Z$, then $\{\bar v_1, \dots, \bar v_N\}$ are always attractors of the dynamics of $f$"?